# Can't read or write images from D Drive [OpenCV] [Python]

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

Is there a way to write or read images on D Drive with OpenCV?

```
writing_directory = "D:/path/"
...
image_path = "D:/path/image.bmp"
image = cv2.imread(image_path)
...
cv2.imwrite(f"{writing_directory}written_image.bmp", image)
```

When I read the image, cv2.imread returns None. When I try to write on D Drive an image which I read from C Drive, it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score -1):

you need to specify your path with r strings.

```
writing_directory = "D:/path/"
...
image = cv2.imread(r"D:/path/image.bmp")
...
cv2.imwrite(fr"{writing_directory}written_image.bmp", image)
```

Comment: «image = cv2.imread(fr"{image_path}")» and «cv2.imwrite(fr"{writing_directory}/filtered.bmp", filtered)» didn't work.

Comment: what was your error?

Comment: cv2.imread returns None and cv2.imwrite does nothing (doesn't even raise an error).

Comment: try using \ instead of / in file path